# VueJS: Get left, top position of element?

Tags: vue.js

While converting legacy jquery code, I stuck at getting position of element.

My goal is display floating `div` above `a` tag.

Here is my template.

```
<a href="#none" v-for="busstop in busstops"
   :id="busstop.id"
   @mouseenter="onMouseEnterBusStop"
   @mouseleave="onMouseLeaveBusStop"
   onclick="detailsOpen(this);">
<div :class="['marker-info', markInfoBusStop.markerInfoActiveClass]"
     :style="markInfoBusStop.markerInfoStyle">
    <p><strong>{{markInfoBusStop.busStopNo}}</strong>{{markInfoBusStop.busStopName}}</p>
    <dl>
      ...
    </dl>
</div>
```

Vue code is below.

```
data: {
  markInfoBusStop: { 
      busStopNo: '12345',
      markerInfoActiveClass: '',
      markerInfoStyle: {
        left: '200px',
        top: '200px'
      }
  },
  ...
},
methods: {
  onMouseEnterBusStop: function(ev) {
    let left = ev.clientX;
    let top = ev.clientY;
    this.markInfoBusStop.markerInfoActiveClass = 'active';
    this.markInfoBusStop.markerInfoStyle.left = left + 'px';
    this.markInfoBusStop.markerInfoStyle.top = top + 'px';
}
```

I'm just using current mouse pointer's position, but need element's absolute position.

My legacy jquery is using `$(this).position()` as below.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "a.marker", function() {
    var left = $(this).position().left;
    var top = $(this).position().top;
    $(".marker-info").stop().addClass("active").css({"left":left, "top": top});
});
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is not a Vue question per se, but more a javascript question. The common way to do this now is by using the element.getBoundingClientRect() method. In your case this would be:

Create a [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) on your `<a>` element and pass that ref in a method like this:

```
<a ref = "busstop" 
     href="#none"  
    v-for="busstop in busstops" 
    @click = getPos(busstop)>
```

In your methods object create the method to handle the click:

```
methods: {
    getPos(busstop) {
         const left = this.$refs.busstop.getBoundingClientRect().left
         const top = this.$refs.busstop.getBoundingClientRect().top
         ...
    }
}
```

Supported by all current browsers:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=getboundingclientrect

More info here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to know the `<a>' tag position then display popup above the a tag.

As your answer,
I modified be below.
let position = document.getElementById(assetID).getBoundingClientRect();
              let left = position.x;
              let top = position.top;

But, too big.

Comment: I realize that I wasn't totally clear. Updating now.

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect` is not a function, while `$refs.myref` is not empty (alerts an HTMLObject)

Answer (score 2):

```
this.markInfoBusStop.markerInfoStyle.left = left + 'px';
```

Above isn't reactive.

#### 1. use Vue.set

[See Doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)

#### 2. use computed

for example (you still need to customize to fit your needs.)

**data**

```
{
 left: 200,
 top: 200,
}
```

**method**

```
onMouseEnterBusStop: function(ev) {
  this.left = ev.clientX;
  this.top = ev.clientY;
}
```

**computed**

```
markerInfoStyle: function(){
  return {
    left: this.left + 'px',
    top: this.top + 'px'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But I want to get the `<a>` tag's abolution position not mouse pointer's position which coded for workaround.  
Could you let me know this?

Comment: I'm not sure whether Vue has the plugin to get the element position directly, you could survey more to check it out, or use @Imre_G 's answer.