# Window is not defined in nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

So, I wanted to bind style with the height of another element that I got from getHeight function, but I kept getting an error that said window is not defined.

Can someone please give me a solution?

Here is my source code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="section-title">past event</p>
    <div class="columns is-multiline">
      <div
        class="column is-one-third is-centered past-events"
        v-for="(event, index) in events.slice(0, 2)"
        :key="index"
      >
        <EventCard :event="event" />
      </div>
      <div class="column is-one-third is-centered">
        <div class="link-box" :style="{ height: getHeight() }">
          <nuxt-link to="/past-events">
            <p style="color: #ffffff; cursor: pointer" class="see-all">
              Lihat List Event Lainnya
            </p>
          </nuxt-link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="see-all-btn"> </a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import EventCard from "~/components/EventCard.vue";

export default {
  name: "PastEvents",
  components: {
    EventCard
  },
  props: ["events"],
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getHeight();
  },
  methods: {
    getHeight() {
      const height = window.getComputedStyle(
        document.querySelector(".past-events")
      ).height;
      console.log(height);
      return height + "px";
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt uses server-sided rendering. This means that when your code is being executed on the server, it does not have something like `window`. After all, it is not a browser.

The easiest way around this is by wrapping anything that should not be pre-rendered to html, with something like [`vue-no-ssr`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-no-ssr). This particular library renders a dummy component on the server, then actually renders the component when it gets to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `window` doesn't exist during the `mounted` lifecycle hook. I assume you're trying to place something based on its position?

In that case, you *might* be able to utilize CSS to do it for you. You can place elements using the View Height/View Width units. Combine that with CSS `calc()` and you might get the solution you need.

Example:

```
.element {
  /* make element positon relative to the window */
  position: fixed;
  /* set position - note vw/vh are % of window */
  /* this put the top of your element -200px from the bottom of your window */
  top: calc(100vh - 200px);
}
```

---

**If you're doing something more complex**, using Javascript's `element.getBoundingClientRect()` will likely provide what you need. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53608536/vuejs-get-left-top-position-of-element) for more info.

Comment: Which part? The CSS solution or the javascript one?

Comment: The javascript one